# Report on all TFS contents?

Tags: tfs

Managers are asking for a report that tells them what IP we have. I am wondering if a report can be generated from TFS that just shows the contents, the folders really, then I would have to add a human assessment of what everything is, what its written in, and what it does.

Is there anything that can help me do less work towards such a report and which assists when there are new projects added?

Background : I have never worked with any TFS reports and I don't know what tech is required to generate them. Essentially I am a very basic check-in/check-out user of TFS.

Comment: You need to see what folders are in source control? Does `dir /s` not work well enough? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can query the tfs_warehouse database to get a list of folders.